# How to for loop in reverse?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop, simulation

I'm making a water simulation program, and I need it to do a for loop through y, x. But I need it to check the most bottom y first, then up. This is my lvl:

```
lvl = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I need it to check lvl[4] and then lvl[3], lvl[2], etc. Please help!

NB: I'm using nested for loops, so I can check y, x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) built-in method to reverse the ordering of your list of lists:

```
for li in reversed(lvl):
    print li
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `for` loops, you can use [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) to generate a reversed sequence to index `lvl` with.

```
>>> range(4,-1,-1)
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

i.e., maybe something similar to:

```
>>> for i in range(4,-1,-1):
...     print lvl[i]
...
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
>>>
```