# Checking in a string from the last character to the first one

Tags: python

I want to check in a string from the last character to the first one using while loop in python.

Linux - Ubuntu - I am using Atom text editor.

```
fruit = 'banana'
letter = fruit[5]
length = len(fruit)
index = 5

    while index > len(fruit):
            letter = fruit[index]
            print(letter)
            index = index - 1
```

the terminal lists the characters right but does that twice and at the end displays out of range error. check:

```
a
n
a
n
a
b
a
n
a
n
a
b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube.py", line 5, in <module>
    letter = fruit[index]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop backwards using indices in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869885/loop-backwards-using-indices-in-python)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This code as posted doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: I flagged as possible dupe, but if you *need* to use a while-loop, just write `while index >= 0` instead -- edit: and start with `length = len(fruit) - 1`

Comment: Uh yeah, as @Carcigenicate mentioned, your code surely doesn't produce the output you documented

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957812/how-to-for-loop-in-reverse

Comment: @wwii Just like my flag, yours ignores the fact that OA asked for a solution using a while-loop

Answer (score 0):

Since your index is starting at 5 and heading down, change your test to `index >= 0`

```py
fruit = 'banana'
letter = fruit[5]
index = 5

while index >= 0:
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter)
    index = index - 1
```

Comment: Hmm, sure, but also set `length` to `len(fruit) - 1` if you want it to work

Comment: @hugo `length` isn't used.  It can be deleted.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Still writing `index = len(fruit) - 1` would be better? *(but I understand your goal was not to alter the original code too much)*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I tried the below and it worked. I used the break functionality.

```
fruit = 'banana'
index = 0
while index < len(fruit) :
    letter = fruit[index - 1]
    print(letter)
    index = index - 1
    if index == -6 :
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods

- reverse slicing

  ```
  fruit = 'banana'
  for f in fruits[::-1]:
     print(f)
  ```
- `reversed` in-build

  ```
  fruit = 'banana'
  for f in reversed(fruits):
     print(f)
  ```
- `while` loop

  ```
  fruit = 'banana'
  fruit_len = len(fruit)
  while fruit_len:
      fruit_len -=1
      print(fruit[fruit_len])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works:

```
index = 0
fruit = "apple"
    while index < len(fruit):
    index = index - 1
        if index < -(len(fruit)):
            break
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter)
```